# How do I design unit tests for my Python webcam script?

Tags: python, unit-testing, webcam, edge-detection

I showed this basic Python script that I hacked together using the internet to a company that does Python image stuff and they ended the interview when I couldn't answer the question "how would you design image tests for this?"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    video, frame = vc.read()
else:
    video = False

while video:
    edges = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200)
    cv2.imshow("preview", edges)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Now the question is ringing through my head and I still don't know the answer. Can anyone help me get started, or demonstrate an example?

Comment: Your showing some code how to use cv2. Unit testing is about testing a (small) part of your unit (=class). So, for me, your question is unclear. Do you mean unittesting of your own class (which uses cv2) or unittesting cv2 itself?

Comment: I think the interviewer was asking about writing Unit Tests for this script, not for cv2 itself.

Comment: That's useless, Unit Testing is about testing an individual component using their API/interface. You don't have an interface, it just a sequence of actions using the interface of cv2.